# Override theme's WooCommerce file

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

Normally we can add WooCommerce files to the theme so that it will override the default WooCommerce files.

But I am developing a plugin which is having some extra feature to the WooCommerce page and I want it to override the theme's WooCommerce files with its own files.

For now, I am adding the modified code of my plugin to the theme itself for making it work. But I want those files to run directly from the plugin so that I don't need to add those files each time I change the theme.

My main concern is the single product page (both simple and variable product).

Any helpful tips?

Comment: edit your question to show the code you use in the template file (and which file ?).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`wc_get_template`](http://hookr.io/filters/wc_get_template/) filter, which allows you to override the absolute filepath to a template just before it's included. For example, this overrides `checkout/payment.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', function ( $file, $name ) {
    if ( $name === 'checkout/payment.php' ) {
        // $file must be an absolute filepath

        // e.g. path relative to current file
        $file = __dir__ . '/templates/checkout/payment.php';

        // e.g. path relative to parent directory
        $file = dirname( __dir__ ) . '/templates/checkout/payment.php';
    }

    return $file;
}, 10, 2 );
```